# Convert to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
with services as (

   select 1 id_service, 1 id_contract, to_date('01.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_start, to_date(null) date_stop from dual union all

   select 2, 1, to_date('01.02.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('01.03.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all

   select 3, 1, to_date('01.02.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('01.03.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all

   select 4, 2, to_date('01.11.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('01.05.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all

   select 5, 2, to_date('05.03.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date(null) from dual union all

   select 6, 2, to_date('01.02.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all

   select 7, 3, to_date('01.02.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all

   select 8, 3, to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all

   select 9, 3, to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('01.03.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
)

select * from services
```

How can I convert this Oracle to Mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `to_date()` calls with MySQL `str_to_date()` and then simply **remove `from dual`**. Like this:

```
select 1 id_service, 1 id_contract, str_to_date('01.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_start, null date_stop union all
select 2, 1, str_to_date('01.02.2019', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.03.2019', '%d.%m.%Y')  union all
select 3, 1, str_to_date('01.02.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.03.2019', '%d.%m.%Y')  union all
select 4, 2, str_to_date('01.11.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.05.2019', '%d.%m.%Y')  union all
select 5, 2, str_to_date('05.03.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), null union all
select 6, 2, str_to_date('01.02.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('31.12.2018', '%d.%m.%Y')  union all
select 7, 3, str_to_date('01.02.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('31.12.2018', '%d.%m.%Y')  union all
select 8, 3, str_to_date('01.01.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('31.12.2018', '%d.%m.%Y')  union all
select 9, 3, str_to_date('01.01.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.03.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11ddc5fc10242d5dd0d2837cf112e679).

Note that to use a WITH clause in MySQL you need to be running a modern version like 8. It's not supported in MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in MySQL you want to achieve a result like this...

```
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id_service | id_contract | date_start | date_stop  |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |           1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|          2 |           1 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-03-01 |
|          3 |           1 | 2017-02-01 | 2019-03-01 |
|          4 |           2 | 2018-11-01 | 2019-05-01 |
|          5 |           2 | 2017-03-05 | NULL       |
|          6 |           2 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-12-31 |
|          7 |           3 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-12-31 |
|          8 |           3 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-12-31 |
|          9 |           3 | 2018-01-01 | 2017-03-01 |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

...then you can use this...

```
   select 1 id_service, 1 id_contract, str_to_date('01.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_start, null date_stop from dual union all
   select 2, 1, str_to_date('01.02.2019', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.03.2019', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual union all
   select 3, 1, str_to_date('01.02.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.03.2019', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual union all
   select 4, 2, str_to_date('01.11.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.05.2019', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual union all
   select 5, 2, str_to_date('05.03.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), null from dual union all
   select 6, 2, str_to_date('01.02.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('31.12.2018', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual union all
   select 7, 3, str_to_date('01.02.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('31.12.2018', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual union all
   select 8, 3, str_to_date('01.01.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('31.12.2018', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual union all
   select 9, 3, str_to_date('01.01.2018', '%d.%m.%Y'), str_to_date('01.03.2017', '%d.%m.%Y') from dual
```

Note that MySQL has the concept of 'dual', but it's not actually necessary here.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked - how do you return multiple rows? `from dual` is used because Oracle doesn't have (or didn't have) table value constructors. In MariaDB, PostgreSQL and SQL Server one can write `VALUES ( ROW(a1,b1,c1), ROW(a2,b2,c3))` or `VALUES ( (a1,b1,c1), (a2,b2,c3))` to specify multiple rows at once

Comment: yep...I'm confused with dual

Comment: Or is there smth similar in SQL?

Comment: MySQL has the concept of 'dual', but it's not actually necessary here.